# Checking XML attribute value

Tags: php, xml

I'm exporting data from XML file in order to update my database. I'm using the following loop:

```
foreach ($xml->removed->idof as $idof) {
  if ($idof > 0) {
    mysql_query("delete from wp_posts WHERE import_id = '$idof'");
    echo $idof;
  }
}
```

My data structure looks like this:

```
<removed>
<idof mlssta='4'>0</idof>
<idof mlssta='6'>60370</idof>
<idof mlssta='14'>150370</idof>
<idof mlssta='6'>150671</idof>
...
</removed>
```

I need to change the `if` condition in order to check the value of `mlstaa` attribute, i.e. `if ($idof > 0 && mlstaa != 6)`.

I just don't know how extract it. Really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `$xml` variable looks like it is loaded with SimpleXML extension. Suppose it is initialized like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('some-file.xml');
```

Then you just fetch attributes with [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) and check if the attribute is in the returned array:

```
foreach ($xml as $idof) {
  $attr = $idof->attributes();
  if ($attr && $attr['mlssta'] != 6) {
    // remove it here
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: @Chichi I know, but still need to wait some time before making so, it just does not allow me.